# How to fix Pyrogram 520 Unknown error Exception that seemingly comes randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

I use the [pyrogram python library](https://docs.pyrogram.org/index) often. I encounter the following error very frequently, and haven't found a way to solve it. It comes seemingly randomly, which is odd considering that I am not being rate limited by the Telegram servers. The following message is the error that I encounter randomly:

```
pyrogram.errors.rpc_error.UnknownError: [520 Unknown error]: [-503 Timeout] (caused by "upload.GetFile")
```

Has anyone ever faced this error themselves, and how have you managed to fix it? What are its causes, if not rate-limiting?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/664) on the pyrogram GitHub repository, if this issue happens a lot then it is a server issue. However, it is mishandled by pyrogram. If it keeps happening for you, then consider using a different endpoint/method to achieve what you are trying to do, as this is a server-side problem and will arise, no matter which module you use.

The best nugget of information I managed to find from that thread was from [this answer](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/664#issuecomment-817343447), which recommends that you use the following method instead:

```py
path = client.download_media(m.photo, file_name="test1.jpg", block=False)
```